# how to include the svg icons on <md-icon> in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

### in html

```
<md-button class="md-fab  md-primary" aria-label="Use Android">
     <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/andriod.svg">
</md-icon></md-button>
```

in the above html i am adding a svg image to fab button using angular material.but unfortunately it is showing an error Cannot GET /img/icons/andriod.svg. I specified the path of the icon in my same directory where html is located.Is there further dependencies are there to be added  to get the affect of icons?

I am new to angular material. can any one please help me.

Comment: What is the full path to andriod.svg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I specified the path of the icon in my same directory where html is
>   located

If your `svg` is in same directory as your html, then shouldn't this `LOC` be changed from

```
<md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/andriod.svg">
```

to

```
<md-icon md-svg-src="/andriod.svg">
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.tried but still showing the same issue.